# What does 'computational' mean in the context of physical theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

In this video titled ["Consciousness is Not a Computation"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXgqik6HXc0&t=1198s), Roger Penrose discusses some of his ideas on consciousness and links with quantum mechanics. I am very curious to what Roger Penrose means when he says that some people view consciousness as 'computational' or 'not computational' (around 17.20 in the video). Specifically, what does a 'computational' theory refer to in physics?

In my mind, computational physics is about modelling physical systems algorithmically and using computers, software etc. But I have no idea what it means for a physical theory itself to be either 'computational' or not. For example, in the video (around 18.50), Roger Penrose says *"... my view is almost the exact opposite of that... it's the state reduces itself, in some way... in some non computational way we don't understand"*. I believe he was referring to a quantum state. **What does it mean for a quantum state reducing to not be computational, and in general for a physical theory to be either computational or not?** For example, does it simply mean that the 'output' of some physical process is simply not predictable, even with perfect knowledge of the inputs to the system?

I have no background in physics, and would appreciate if there was some appropriate mathematical formalisation of computation (if that makes sense). I also expected this question would likely have been asked already, but I couldn't find it by searching either on the site or via google, so I would also be very appreciative for any links to similar questions that have already been asked.